# using awk and stat in one line to print values of stat

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, stat

Below is the script which I'm trying to run. I cannot use stat inside awk.

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $6 }' | (stat $6 | sed -n '/^Access: (/{s/Access: (\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/;p}' })'
```

My desired output should be like this:

```
 /root 0550 
 /bin  0777
 /sbin 0777
```

I'm able to write the script using while or for.. but I want all the script to be in one line without loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should work?

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{cmd="stat -c\"'%a'\" "$6 ; cmd  | getline perm; close(cmd); printf "%s\t%s\n",$6,perm }' /etc/passwd
```

Edit 1:
A brief explanation:

```
BEGIN{
  FS=":"  # set field separator 
}
{
  cmd="stat -c\"'%a'\" "$6 ; # define stat as a command w/ only perms as output
  cmd  | getline perm; # capture those perms for the current $6
  close(cmd);  # close the pipe, good practice to get into
  printf "%s\t%s\n",$6,perm # print the directory name and the correlated perms
}
```

Comment: this works great. but, how can I include to print the name of the home directory also? can you please explain me this script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by **print the name of the home directory also**.  It prints $6 (as in your brief) and its perms.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I want to print $1 in awk which is the user. sample output: username user_homedirectory permissions  root /root 755

Comment: In that case just modify `printf "%s\t%s\n",$6,perm` to `printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,perm` ... easy..

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be a lot easier / faster if you do it all in perl:

```
perl -we 'while (@pw = getpwent) { $d = $pw[7]; @st = stat $d or do { warn "$d: $!\n"; next }; printf "%s %s %04o\n", $pw[0], $d, $st[2] & 07777 }'
```

Advantages:

- no need to parse `/etc/passwd` manually
- no need to spawn external processes, especially not one extra process per line
- no need to reparse the output from `stat`
- easy and flexible output formatting with `printf`

Answer (score 0):

of course `$6` doesn't mean what you think outside of `awk`, you can do instead

```
$ awk -F: '{print $6}' /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 stat | sed  ...
```

Comment: this doesn't print the home directory?

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk has a sample extension `filefuncs` which has `stat` function. Below is based on sample code from its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Internal-File-Description.html):

```
$ echo /tmp | awk -F: '                           # testing with echo
@load "filefuncs";                                # enable extension
{
    ret = stat($1,fdata)                          # stat the file
    if (ret < 0)                                  # if file not exists
        printf("could not stat %s: %s\n",file, ERRNO) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf "%s %o\n",fdata["name"],fdata["mode"]  # print name and mode 16 bit
}' 
/tmp 41777
```

If you want to try that, replace the `$1` with `$6` and use it like `awk '{...}' /etc/passwd` You also may need to set shell variable AWKLIBPATH for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is not mandatory:

```
stat -c '%n %#8a' <pathnames>
```

Also look at `stat --printf`, and `--terse` which prints a bunch of stuff on one line.